# segmentation fault on scanning and print string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

When I tried to use only INT arguments, it worked perfectly, but when I try to use strings I always get "Segmentation Fault" and I don't know why.
I know it might be a silly mistake, but would anyone care to explain it to me, please?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct cliente{
    char *nome;
    int idade;
}t_cliente;


int main(){

    t_cliente *vet;
    int qtdCliente, i, j;

    scanf("%d", &qtdCliente);

    vet=(t_cliente*)malloc(qtdCliente*sizeof(t_cliente));

    for(i=0; i<qtdCliente; i++){
        scanf("%s", vet[i].nome);
        scanf("%d", &vet[i].idade); 
    }

    for(j=0; j<qtdCliente; j++){
        printf("%s\n", vet[j].nome);
        printf("%d\n", vet[j].idade);   
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(vet);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried using this line of code, but still wouldn't work:   
vet->nome=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

Comment: You will need to allocate memory for each `t_cliente` in the array, possibly inside the for i loop.

Comment: Thank you! Now it worked (:

Answer (score 1):

```
vet=(t_cliente*)malloc(qtdCliente*sizeof(t_cliente));
```

(and the cast is both unnecessary *and* unwise in C) will give you an array of structures, each containing the two fields `nome` and `idade`.

However, `nome` in each structure will be set to an *arbitrary* value so the statement:

```
scanf("%s", vet[i].nome);
```

will almost certainly attempt to write to memory that it shouldn't be writing to.

Assuming you *know* what the maximum size will be for the first field, you would be better off defining it as something like:

```
#define MAXNOME 50
typedef struct cliente{
    char nome[MAXNOME];
    int idade;
}t_cliente;
```

That way, the memory you will attempt to write to will at least be valid.

However, people who use `scanf("%s",...)` often don't realise how bad a practice it is. It can lead to buffer overflow problems since there is no way to specify a limit on the characters that will be written to the buffer. There are much safer ways to do this (get user input), such as the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

Comment: and even if some memory is allocated for the string, you need to make sure that the `scanf` doesn't read a string longer than that!

Comment: @user3121023, that often introduces other problems such as what happens if you enter 60 characters then the next thing you want is an integer. I prefer line-based user input so I can tell when things begin and end, leaving `scanf`-like functionality for files where I control the format. Someone else put it better than I: "scanf stands for 'scan formatted' and there's precious few things that are *less* formatted than user input" :-)